# How can I create a dictionary of N elements dynamically?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a list of varying number of groups N (this number is a parameter to my function).

Basically, I would like to create N groups of scores on the fly, ​so that if I specify N to be 3 for example, it will create a dictionary containing the N groups. Here is the hardcoded version:

```
groups = [(1, 1, 1, 1)]
levels_list = []
for group in groups:
    level0 = 0
    scores = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    level1 = scores[int(max(level0) + 1): int((max(level0) + 1) + group[1])]
    level2 = scores[int(max(level1) + 1): int((max(level1) + 1) + group[2])]
    level3 = scores[int(max(level2) + 1): int((max(level2) + 1) + group[3])]
    levels = {'nothing': level0, 'one_thing': level1, 'several_things': level2, 'loads_of_things': level3}
    levels_list.append(levels)
```

​I presume the pseudo code, where N is a parameter "self.params.n_groups" would be something like the following:

```
levels_dict = {}
for group in groups:
    levels = [0] # initialize a list with the first level as 0
    scores = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    level = self.create_levels(levels, group, scores)
    levels_dict[level] = level

def create_levels(self, levels, group, scores):
     for n in range(self.params.n_groups):
         # how to write this part?
​         level = grades[int(max(levels[i]) + 1): int((max(levels[i]) + 1) + group[i+1])]
    return level
```

I'm having difficulty with the create_levels function, specifically calling level{n} (if I apply formatting to it, it is not recognized as an existing variable, but a string). I need to dynamically insert the previous 'level' variable (level0, level1, level2 etc) into that calculation.

Comment: what do you mean by "having difficulty"? what have you tried? what is/isn't working?

Comment: Where are the keys of the `levels` dictionary coming from?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  Sorry, I just edited my explanation, I hope the code is clearer now.

Comment: @MohammadAthar Specifically calling the 'level' from the previous calculation (level1 calculation requires level0, etc). Should I store the levels in a list and call to them each time from within the create_levels function? pardon but I am a novice at this...

Comment: are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: thanks! solved it with recursion, i will post the updated solution above :)